# What kind of return type is SUBSTRING in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, substring

I have a stored procedure with this input parameter:

```
@String = "ABC"
```

Then, inside the stored procedure, I'm using the `SUBSTRING` function

```
SET @Var = SUBSTRING(@String, 4, 5)
```

My question is: what kind of result will I get in  `@Var`?

1. Blank Space
2. NULL
3. None of this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could just RTFM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms187748.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See the results:

```
declare @String varchar(max) = 'ABC'
declare @var varchar(max)
SET @Var = SUBSTRING(@String, 4, 5)
select @var
```

It will give you Empty results like:

[image: this]

Comment: so , the result is: "withe space"?